# Unable to download the file as attachment in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi Im facing issue while dowloading the file in Node Js im using post and get methods . Below is my code

```
router.post('/download',function(req,res,next){
    var files=req.body;
    console.log(files[0]);
    var file_url = 'D:/Techh/Orginal/configR/uploads/'+files[0];
    console.log(file_url);
    res.redirect('/'+files[0]);
});
```

Above service is called from the client and later it is redirected to below service

```
app.get('/:file(*)', function(req, res, next){
    var file = '/'+req.params.file, path = 'D:/Techh/Orginal/configR/uploads' +file; 
    res.download(path);
});
```

But I'm unable to see the file getting downloaded in browser instead I'm able to see the response in the browser console shown in below image

> [image: img]

Comment: Are you requesting the download using AJAX? How does it get logged to the console?

Comment: By this way you expose your entire filesystem to the internet

Comment: What is the code in the browser? Why do you expect the response to be "downloaded"? It's already downloaded, it's in your console. What is your goal?

Comment: Yes Im using asynchronous call in Angular2 and i was consoling the result when i remove that im unable to see it in console . But my goal is to download the file from browser which is not happening

Comment: Like I showed in my answer, you need to simply set `window.location.href` to a URL that makes the server send the file.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your intention, you want to basically start a download when the user clicks something, without leaving the page.
Since the server is sending the file as download, all you need to do on the client is

```
window.location.href = "/download/filename";
```

The server should handle a GET to `/download/:filename` by calling `res.download()`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ajax, use submit into an iframe. We'll able to see file download in the browser

```
 <FORM action="http://example.com/script.php" 
       method="POST" target="hidden-form">
  <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="sdsfsfd"/>
</FORM>
<IFRAME style="display:none" name="hidden-form"></IFRAME>
```

In addition, something like this

```
'D:/Techh/Orginal/configR/uploads/'+files[0];
```

is quite dangerous if someone try something like ../../../../secretfile, etc.. Clear path before :

```
var a = "../../../sdfsdf.txt"
a.substr(a.lastIndexOf("/")+1); // sdfsdf.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the header? I can't see it set in your code so I'd suggest that you set the content-type on your response.

Have a look here for a better understanding of response headers:
[Node.js Documentation about response header](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value)

And refer to this question solution for an example of the implementation:

[StackOverflow question about pdf file download using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802152/unable-to-download-the-file-as-attachment-in-node-js)

Edit: One more thing FYI, the error you getting is because the browser is getting some data and it doesn't know what to do with it. You need to tell him what data is receiving in order for him to know what to do with it. That's why you need the response header, to tell the browser what data is being transmited.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The header is set by the call to `res.download()`. The problem is that the OP is making an AJAX request to a file, which means it ends up in the response instead of triggering the browser to start a download.

Comment: @ChrisG, can you provide the evidence about that? I've looked over the Nodejs documentation and Expressjs documentation and both of them stress the same about setting the content type. Unless the op is using something else, my suggestion is correct.

Comment: Note that I'm not referring to the Ajax request, I haven't tried it so I can't really tell if that's an issue or not.

Comment: http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res.download Quote: "Transfers the file at path as an “attachment”. Typically, browsers will prompt the user for download." OP said he uses an "asynchronous call in Angular2". i.e. AJAX.

Comment: @ChrisG that doesn't invalidate my point. Yes it does sends the file as an attachment but it doesn't sets the header. And it is visible that the file is inside the response body but it's not prompting, and my guess is because the browser doesn't know what in hell is in response body. But let's wait for the OP to see.

Comment: Plus if you scroll down few pixels more you'll see this...

_res.type(type)
Sets the Content-Type HTTP header to the MIME type as determined by mime.lookup() for the specified type. If type contains the “/” character, then it sets the Content-Type to type._

[link](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res.set)

Comment: You are wrong. Feel free to test it yourself, like I did. *Only* calling `.download()` *does* set `content-disposition` to `attachment`. `content-type` is completely unrelated to this issue. Plus, *AGAIN*, the problem is the AJAX call, as opposed to clicking a link or setting `window.location.href`. That's because regardless of `attachment` or not, the response ends up in the AJAX handler.